# How to extract text from html String

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to extract text from an html string but, it is not working as expected.

The html string I have is,

```
<div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main">&lt;p&gt;The Angelina Tank Dress is simple yet sophisticated. This dress can be thrown over a swimsuit for last minute lunch plans or belted for dinner on the patio. The high-low hemline gives it the perfect amount of swing. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Features:&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Scoopneck&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Sleeveless&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Hits below the knee&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Longer back hemline&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine wash, tumble dry low&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;</div>
```

There is a description text and text inside the ul li elements. How could I extract all of that text separately. For example, extract the description text separately and the text inside li elements separately.

I tried

```
 const productDescription = productDetails.description.replace(/<div>|<\/div>|<ul>|<li>/g, "").trim().split("Features:");
```

I would like the text to be

The Angelina Tank Dress is simple yet sophisticated. This dress can be thrown over a swimsuit for last minute lunch plans or belted for dinner on the patio. The high-low hemline gives it the perfect amount of swing.

Scoopneck
Sleeveless
Hits below the knee
Longer back hemline
Machine wash, tumble dry low

Comment: document.getElementById('#elementid').textContent or .innerText depending on the neeed

Comment: Don't attempt to parse html with regex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6333444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

    function stripHtml(html) {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.innerHTML = html;
        var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("p");
        temporalDivElement.innerHTML = textarea.value;
        return temporalDivElement.textContent || temporalDivElement.innerText || "";
    }




    var htmlString = `<div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default " data-element="main">&lt;p&gt;The Angelina Tank Dress is simple yet sophisticated. This dress can be thrown over a swimsuit for last minute lunch plans or belted for dinner on the patio. The high-low hemline gives it the perfect amount of swing. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Features:&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Scoopneck&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Sleeveless&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Hits below the knee&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Longer back hemline&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine wash, tumble dry low&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;</div>`;

    console.log(stripHtml(htmlString));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the text content of the element.
2. Create a new temporary div element, and add the text content as *HTML* to that element.
3. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all the `p` and `li` elements.
4. Iterate over that node list (after creating an array from it so we can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).
5. For each node check [it's nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName), and return a useful object with `type` and `text` properties.

```js
const html = document.querySelector('div').textContent;

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;

const els = div.querySelectorAll('p, li');

const arr = Array.from(els).map(el => {
  const type = el.nodeName === 'P' ? 'para' : 'item';
  return { type, text: el.textContent }
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main">&lt;p&gt;The Angelina Tank Dress is simple yet sophisticated. This dress can be thrown over a swimsuit for last minute lunch plans or belted for dinner on the patio. The high-low hemline gives it the perfect amount of swing. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Features:&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Scoopneck&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Sleeveless&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Hits below the knee&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Longer back hemline&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine wash, tumble dry low&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;</div>
```