# How to extract text from a html tag in text format?

Tags: javascript, html

I have below html tag in text format.

```
const text = '<td rowspan="3" colspan="2" class="confluenceTd">All Best <br><br></td>';
```

I want to extract both the text, rowspan & colspan from above i.e. **All Best**, **3**, **2** respectivelly.
Any help appreciated!!.

Comment: You're using JavaScript so convert the string to a DOM object. Regex is silly for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text from html String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72573421/how-to-extract-text-from-html-string)

Answer (score 2):

Create an element out of it then query for those attributes. Since we are talking about `td` it has no life without a table (implicit or explicit) so we wrap it inside a table to make it valid and targetable by `querySelector`.

```js
const text = '<td rowspan="3" colspan="2" class="confluenceTd">All Best <br><br></td>';
var table = '<table><tr>' + text + '</tr></table>';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = table;
var elem = div.querySelector("tr").firstChild
console.log(elem.getAttribute("rowspan"));
console.log(elem.getAttribute("colspan"));
console.log(elem.innerText);
```